# Spell Slots at Paladin 5/Sorcerer 1

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, paladin, spell-slots

I've started a new campaign group, with a Paladin main, but starting to spec into Sorcerer, with currently 4 1st level , and 2 2nd level spell slots, however my dm is not sure if that's correct, and this my first time multiclassing into any caster so I have no clue.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Jack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. I’ve closed this as a duplicate, it’s a pretty common question, as the rules for spellcasting and spell slots when multiclassing can be a bit confusing at first.